# Why I cannot use a table alias inside a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT customers.id, customers.name, o.order_date
FROM customers, 
    (SELECT id, 
     order_date 
     FROM orders ORDER BY order_date DESC) as o
WHERE o.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM o
    WHERE customer_id = customers.id
    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

However it results with an error
`relation "o" does not exist`

I understand that there is an issue with an alias of a subquery above it but I don't know how can I fix it. The reason why I'm not referencing "orders" table directly in WHERE clause is because I want to optimise it by creating a subquery with just 2 columns which are ordered, so this query is not executed on entire table each time a comparison in WHERE clause is made (is it how it works?).

Is there any other way I can write this query?

Comment: This query looks - even when changing it as proposed in the answer - very complicated and the question is if this is really necessary. Maybe you could show sample input and expected outcome and people here can think about a better query?

Comment: @JonasMetzler The reason why I'm not doing a simple join is because I want to join only the first match from orders table based on date (most recent one) - this is done using the second subquery. And the first subquery is used to reduce the size of the orders table to just few columns, so it is done once and not each time it is referenced in the second subquery. However I am not 100% sure if this really leads to optimisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the only problem with your query - you're also referencing `customer_id` that you did not select from `orders`. Once you fix that and move your subquery to a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), it'll work:

```sql
with o as (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    customer_id,
    order_date 
  FROM orders 
  ORDER BY order_date DESC)
SELECT 
  customers.id, 
  customers.name, 
  o.order_date
FROM customers, 
     o
WHERE o.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM o
    WHERE o.customer_id = customers.id
    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RPC6R5X6)

[EDIT:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351164/why-i-cannot-use-a-table-alias-inside-a-subquery/74351256#comment131260708_74351357)

> When I am joining these tables I want to join only first match from orders table based on date (the most recent one)

[`MAX()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) would be sufficient to get customers and their most recent order dates.

```sql
SELECT 
  c.id, 
  c.name, 
  max(o.order_date) as most_recent_order_date
FROM customers c 
  left join orders o 
  on o.customer_id=c.id
group by c.id, c.name
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Comment: You're right I forgot to put that column in the SELECT statement. With CTE it indeed works as I wanted to. Thanks!

Comment: @Dawid I've added an example of a query simply returning most recent order date per customer - I noticed your comment before the other answer was taken down.

Comment: This is a nice solution too, definitely looks more clean than the first one. Thank you.